# how can find which derive class in vector of base class in c++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of base pointer and need to know which derive class of this base class for example

```
class Document {
protected :
string name;
Date date_borrow; // Date is class
};

class Book : public Document {
private :
int book_pages;
};

class Reference : public Document {
private :
string writer;
};

class Member {
   protected :
        vector < Document* > document;

};
class Library {
public :
void borrow ( Member* member, Document* document ){
   member->add_document ( document );
}
private : 
vector < Document* > documents;
vector < Member* > members;

};
```

in this code when member borrow document , i need to know the document* is a book or reference to calculate penalty for late.
(the function of penalty is different for book and reference)
and then push_back document in documents in private of member. 
how can i find the type of derive?

Comment: Sounds like you want a virtual function, not a check for the type. Your base class is also missing a virtual destructor.

Comment: What is a "reference" and how does one borrow it from a library?

Comment: @NeilKirk: I believe a "Reference" is a reference work, like e.g. some technical manual, as opposed to fiction.

Comment: Doesn't a reference have pages and doesn't a book have a writer? I question the whole need for inheritance here at all.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Yes I agree the design doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for Polymorphism:

```
class Document {
public:
    virtual ~Document() { }
    virtual double latePenalty() = 0; 
};


class Book : public Document {
public:
    double latePenalty() { 
        // book-specific late penalty
        return 5.0 * daysLate() + 17.0; 
    }
};

class Reference: public Document {
public:
    double latePenalty() { 
        // reference-specific late penalty
        return 1e6; // because that'll teach you! 
    }
};

vector < Document* > documents;
```

This way, calling `latePenalty()` will, via dynamic dispatch, call the correct version for each type of `Document`.

Comment: This solution is better if you want the late-penalty functionality to be handled by the objects instead of the library objects.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but two question ( I'm beginner in programming) : 1- what is in line 3?   2-when member borrow document ,the document push_back in   vector < Document* > documents and the date of document is set . but if the library have 3 of this book(the quantity of book is in private) all of the book timed borrow change,and it's wrong,and it's happend because i push_back the pointer that point to library document and if i try to build new pointer i need the type of the document.

Comment: @AAAK [When to use virtual destructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: And I don't understand your second question.

Answer (score 0):

*Technically* you can just put a virtual destructor in the topmost base class, then use `dynamic_cast` to attempt to downcast pointers.

Instead I strongly advice you to put the relevant virtual functions in the pointee class.

Virtual functions are a way to do type-safe, efficient down-casting. Manual down-casting via e.g. `dynamic_cast` is inefficient and error-prone.

Comment: That's not very safe, though, or fast.

Comment: @caps Care you elaborate?

Comment: He edited his answer. Originally he just suggested using dynamic_cast.

Comment: @caps: You're wrong. I edited the answer twice. You are just too trigger-happy. Instead relax a little. Take some time. ;-)

Comment: @caps: No, you're not "wrong", you're **wrong** for stating that originally I just suggested using `dynamic_cast`. That is untrue. You stated this without any evidence. If you had said that was what you saw when you responded, you would have been right. But you jumped to an incorrect conclusion, and that's why you're **wrong**.

Comment: Instead relax a little. Take some time. Reflect. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

What I do in these situations is use an enum.

```
enum document_type { dtBook, dtReference };
```

Then each class would have a member like this:

```
class Document {
protected:
    std::string name;
    Date date_borrow; // Date is a class
public:
    virtual document_type GetType() = 0;
    // note that this makes the class pure virtual. If that is undesirable,
    // you might want to add a third type to the enum, like dtDocument, as
    // a default return value
};

class Book : public Document {
    document_type GetType() {
        return dtBook;
    };

private:
    int book_pages;
};

class Reference : public Document {
    document_type GetType() {
        return dtReference;
    };

private:
    std::string writer;
};
```

Comment: Whenever you derive a new class, you have to remember to update the get type. If I derive from Book, should I return dtBook or my own enum? If the file with enum is locked, how can I add a new id?

Comment: @caps: E.g. google it? Or *Object Oriented Software Construction* by Betrand Meyer. He left out enumeration types in the Eiffel language just to help people avoid this anti-pattern.

Comment: Yup. That's the code treatment that teaches people. Adding your "stuff" to already high entropy mass of code... (Note how others didn't have this problem)